# Concurrency Testing For A Web Service Using Python

Tags: python

I have a web service that is required to handle significant concurrent utilization and volume and I need to test it. Since the service is fairly specialized, it does not lend itself well to a typical testing framework. The test would need to simulate multiple clients concurrently posting to a URL, parsing the resulting Http response, checking that a database has been appropriately updated and making sure certain emails have been correctly sent/received.

The current opinion at my company is that I should write this framework using Python. I have never used Python with multiple threads before and as I was doing my research I came across the Global Interpreter Lock which seems to be the basis of most of Python's concurrency handling. It seems to me that the GIL would prevent Python from being able to achieve true concurrency even on a multi-processor machine. Is this true? Does this scenario change if I use a compiler to compile Python to native code? Am I just barking up the wrong tree entirely and is Python the wrong tool for this job?

Answer (score 3):

The Global Interpreter Lock prevents threads simultaneously executing Python code. This doesn't change when Python is compiled to bytecode, because the bytecode is still run by the Python interpreter, which will enforce the GIL. `threading` works by switching threads every `sys.getcheckinterval()` bytecodes.

This doesn't apply to `multiprocessing`, because it creates multiple Python *processes* instead of threads. You can have as many of those as your system will support, running truly concurrently.

So yes, you can do this with Python, either with `threading` or `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to go with the multiprocessing option and use the library ozk suggested.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Please read this [doc](https://github.com/shamhub/python_programming/blob/master/4_Concurrency%26IPC/Multi-threading/1_GIL.odt)

Answer (score 0):

you can use python's multiprocessing library to achieve this.
http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks! This seems like just the thing. Per katrielalex's comment below, multi-processing seems like the best bet here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming general network conditions, as long you have sufficient system resources Python's regular threading module will allow you to simulate concurrent workload at an higher rate than any a real workload.